# Firestore runTransaction never runs

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am having the strangest problem. One day, out of the blue, runTransaction simply stopped running completely. no errors. no messages. any print statements i put there never runs. nothing. like as if the runTransaction statement is not there at all.

My code is exactly like the example code on the pub. if i just run `update` or `set` or `add` without the transaction it works perfectly.

```
final DocumentReference postRef = Firestore.instance.document('all_tokens/123');
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
                  DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(postRef);
                  if (postSnapshot.exists) {
                    await tx.update(postRef, <String, dynamic>{'likesCount': postSnapshot.data['likesCount'] + 1});
                  }else{
                    await tx.set(postRef, <String, dynamic>{'likesCount': postSnapshot.data['likesCount'] + 1});
                  }
                });
```

No error messages at all. nothing in the `catch`, nothing in `then`. The entire thing never runs. its like its being skipped

here is my pubspeck.yaml :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.2.0
  fluttertoast: ^3.0.4
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^0.1.7
  flutter_image_compress: ^0.4.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.11.0+2
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3
  firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+3
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.2
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.0
  flutter_rating: ^0.0.2
  flutter_typeahead: ^1.4.0
  url_launcher: ^4.0.3
  flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0
  algolia: ^0.1.5
  geolocator: ^4.0.3
  provider: ^2.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I conclude it is a recent version of Flutter that has caused this issue.  I recently upgraded to the latest in the master channel and I started having the same problems.  Once I downgraded to latest build in the Stable channel, the problem went away.

Thanks to [crushman1 for reporting](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33310) this and updating that a downgrade worked for him.  Downgrading to latest stable build fixed it for me as well.

Steps to downgrade can be found [HERE](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels)

Comment: This appears to be fixed with Cloud Firestore 0.12.2.

Comment: Confirmed working again using Stable channel which at the moment uses Flutter 1.5.4+2 Dart 2.3.0.  linking in cloud_firestore 0.12.5+2